# Can I find tables that countains a column name X?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have this large database, and someone asked me to find out what tables has column name X. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query against [all_tab_columns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm) like this:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE column_name LIKE '%your_search_column_name%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `All_tab_columns` system table.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm

```
   SELECT
      TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
   FROM
      ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
   WHERE 
      COLUMN_NAME = ...
```